# Правильний переклад словосполучення «столовая ложка »?

Tags: переклад

Як перекладається на українську мову словосполучення «столовая ложка»? Бачила переклад «столова ложка». Та й в Академічному тлумачному словнику бачила таке словосполучення. Та чи не є це калькою з російської мови? Ми ж не кажемо «столова», а кажемо «їдальня», то, можливо, і це словосполучення має інший переклад.

Comment: Англійською «tablespoon», теж «столова ложка».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По-моєму, цілком нормальне словосполучення — «столова ложка» (навіть якщо воно за походженням є калькою — але прийнятною калькою).

Те, що ми кажемо «їдальня», а не «столова» — тут, по-моєму, ні до чого. Те, що ми кажемо «їдальня», а не «столова», означає, що ми маємо кращий (на мою думку) спосіб назвати приміщення споживання їжі (іменник, а не субстантивований прикметник) — але в нас все одно є прикметник «[столовий](http://sum.in.ua/s/stolovyj)» (що вживається зокрема у значеннях «що має відношення до столу», «призначений для обіднього стола, застосовуваний під час їжі» і «призначений для харчування»). «Столовая ложка» — це ложка, призначена для обіднього столу, а не ложка, призначена для громадських їдалень, тому тут слово «столовий» доречне.

> *Мілька (семилїтня, гарна дївчина, з довгим, роспущеним русявим волосєм, з кошиком на руцї, вскакує. Показуючи мамі срібну столову ложку).* Мамунцю, мамунцю! А дивіть ся, що́ я маю! Купіть менї за те суконьку.
>   <sub>*З [перекладу](//books.google.com/books?id=mDaBcXDD5YMC) (1898) Івана Франка драми [«Ткачі»](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Weber) (1892) Гергарта Гауптмана.*</sub>